# linking 2 excel files with filters

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I have two separate workbooks that I am trying to link: Register and Budget. 
The Register file is the source of data and contains only 1 table with columns Date, Category, Credit, Debit. The Budget file is the destination file and has 12 sheets named for each month of the year. Each sheet contains multiple tables named for the Categories. Each table contains columns in which I want to automatically populate from Register one at a time.

So basically, as I manually populate the Register workbook with values in Date, Category, Credit, Debit, I want the Budget workbook to automatically update itself based on these values. The main problem I have is how do I get the Date entered as 01/01/2016 in Register to be recognized as the January sheet in Budget workbook? In addition, I want the correct Category to be recognized in Register as each table's name in Budget. I have changed the table names in Budget based on the category. Finally, I would like the amounts Credit or Debit to be copied from Register into columns in each table of Budget after finding the correct sheet and table in Budget.

[Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ic2X.png), 
[Budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfO6O.png)

I looked into Vlookup and it works except for the fact I would have to manually change the formula each time the category or date changes. Sum and Count don't work because I don't want to sum columns nor count data. I simply want to copy and paste from columns Credit or Debit in Register into each table's columns in Budget. I have a feeling I'd have to go into VBA coding to achieve this daunting task which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of getting information from other workbooks / sheets etc.
It depends on what you want to do with that information and how it's laid out.

Have a look into `VLOOKUP` / `MATCH` / `SUMIF` / `SUMIFS` / `COUNTIF` / `COUNTIFS`

Which you use will depend on how you want it to work.
If you edit your question to include specifics then I / others can advise further.